# Depth-first Search Non-Reursive Implementation in Clojure

Tags: graph, clojure, depth-first-search

I've created a non-recursive dfs implementation in Clojure. I'm using the wikipedia article on dfs as a guide. I'm very new to Clojure and functional programming in general. Any tips to improve readability, make the code more idiomatic, or improve performance would be very helpful. I'm aware there is already question about a recursive dfs implementation in Clojure, but I feel like this code is different enough to warrant a separate post.

```
(def graph {'a '(b c e) 'b '(a d f) 'c '(a g) 'd '(b) 'e '(a f) 'f '(b e)})

(defn label
  [v discovered]
  (cons v discovered))

(defn get-edges
  [g v]
  (get g v))

(defn labeled?
 [v discovered]
  (cond
    (some #(= v %) discovered) true
    :else false))

(defn build-stack
 [S edges]
  (concat S edges))


(defn dfs
  [g v]
   (loop
    [discovered '() S (cons v ())]
     (cond
      (empty? S) (reverse discovered)
      (labeled? (last S) discovered) (recur discovered (butlast S))
      :else 
       (recur
         (label (last S) discovered) 
         (build-stack (butlast S) (get-edges g (last S)))))))
```

Comment: "but I feel like this code is different enough to warrant a separate post." Don't worry, you almost have to copy the question verbatim to make it a duplicate on Code Review. As long as the code is yours, it doesn't matter whether it solves the same problem others have already done a hundred times.

Comment: do you want to implement dfs to learn clojure? if you want to make thing done, you can use tree-seq

Comment: Yes, I'd like to learn Clojure. I'll look at tree-seq. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the top ...

- The `label` function is a synonym for `cons`, as is `build-stack` for
  `concat`. Drop them.
- The `get-edges` function doesn't get edges. It gets the neighbouring
  vertices. Call it `neighbours`, or some such.

The `labeled?` function:

- It determines whether the first argument is a member of the
  collection second argument. So call it something generic like
  `includes?`.
- Swap the arguments around, so that it reads more naturally.
- Get rid of the explicit `false`s and `true`s. You usually can.

We end up with

```
(defn includes?
  [coll x]
  (some #(= x %) coll))
```

Now for the `dfs` function itself.

- Your local `S` is, as its name suggests, a stack. Use the other end
  of it - the front of the list. This gets rid of the slow `last` and
  `butlast`. You can't use Clojure's stack lingo - `peek`, `pop`, and
  `conj` - because there's a `concat` in there. So use `first`, `next`,
  and `cons` instead.
- If you use a vector instead of a list to accumulate `discovered`, you
  don't need the final `reverse`.
- `(cons v ())` is just `(list v)`

The result is

```
(defn dfs
  [g v]
  (loop [discovered [], S (list v)]
    (cond
      (empty? S) discovered
      (includes? discovered (first S)) (recur discovered (rest S))
      :else (recur
              (conj discovered (first S))
              (concat (neighbours g (first S)) (rest S))))))
```

---

There's still a performance problem. Whenever it deals with a potentially new vertex, it uses `includes?` to do a linear search of `discovered`. For a graph of `n` vertices, this takes of the order of `n^2` time.

The answer is to hold the discovered data twice:

- as a vector, for returning the answer; and
- as a set, for testing for presence.

This roughly doubles the amount of memory required, but reduces time required enormously (roughly to order of `n`).

I'll leave you to make the necessary changes to `dfs`.